# Mean Square Error of Sample Variance

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics

Define the sample variance of $n$ measurements  as $V_{n}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\,\frac{(X_{i}-M_{n}(X))^2}{n}$, where $M_n({X})$ is the sample mean, for the random variable X. I was trying to find the mean squared error for this estimator, I did by opening the squares and the expanding , but it turns at the summation become too difficult to simplify. Any help to proceed would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Does your equation include a fraction over $n$ ? Consider using \frac{}{}.